How to exclude folder in kotlin DSL build.gradle.kts
     sourceSets {
         main {
           java {
               srcDirs = listOf("src/main/java")
               exclude("com/mediamelon/excludedPackage")  // Exclude the entire package
           }
       }
     }

I am getting error can not find exclude()

Is this DSL used in the android {} or java {} or kotlin {} block?
